# How to extend table with a view in Entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I wanted to have a view to add a few extra proprieties and I tried the following:

Base table:

```
namespace Core.Model {

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    //...
}
}
```

extended view:

```
namespace Core.Model
{

    public class ItemExtended : Item
    {
        public int? CommentsCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in the Context I have:

```
public DbSet<QuiverItemExtended> ItemsExtended { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<ItemExtended>()
    .ToTable("ItemsExtended")
    .HasKey(view => new { view.ItemId });
```

This works for querying but when I try to insert a normal Item I get this exception:

> All objects in the EntitySet 'Context.Items' must have unique primary
>   keys. However, an instance of type 'Core.Model.ItemExtended' and an
>   instance of type 'Core.Model.Item' both have the same primary key
>   value, 'EntitySet=Items;ItemId=1097'.

Any ideias how I can fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382285/entity-framework-and-inheritance-notsupportedexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I will solve this using a calculated column: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx